# How to set X position of a flexbox in CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

at the moment I'm just playing around with flexbox, trying to figure things out, at the moment I've made:
[image]
with the following code:

```css
.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container-1 div {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 0%;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 0%;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 5;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <h1>Box One </h1>
    <p>This is my first paragraph!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <h1>Box Two </h1>
    <p>This is my second paragraph!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <h1>Box Three </h1>
    <p>This is my third paragraph!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Say that I wanted my paragraph 3 to be a sidebar that appears on the right hand side of the screen, how would I do that? Without flex, I'd probably use `position: absolute; width: 20%; left: 80%;`
or something like that, but I don't think that works with flexboxes. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you mean you want `box-3` to be smaller and to the right with the other boxes filling the remaining space? Or just the paragraph in `box-3` to be to the right?

Comment: Your code is telling `box-3` that it shouldn't grow or shrink but also be 60% of the remaining width (`flex: 0 0 60%`). Also, your individual `flex: 5` `flex: 1` will do nothing since you are overriding them immediately with the next line. Those lines are equivalent to saying `flex-grow: 1` or `5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you write the same rule for the same element twice it will be overridden:

```css
.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 0%; /* Only this will be interpreted as a rule */
}
```

Second, if you want the third element to be 20% width and be on the right side, you need to do something like this:

```css
.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
}
      
.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
}
      
.box-3 {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

Third, I wouldn't recommend building layouts with flexbox, I would use instead grids https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

```html
<style>
       .container-1{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      
    .container-1 div{
      border: 1px #ccc solid;
      padding: 10px;
      }
      
      .box-1 {
        flex: 1;
      }
      
      .box-2 {
        flex: 1;
      }
      
      .box-3 {
        flex: 0 0 20%;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container-1">
      <div class="box-1">
        <h1>Box One </h1>
        <p>This is my first paragraph!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box-2">
        <h1>Box Two </h1>
        <p>This is my second paragraph!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box-3">
        <h1>Box Three </h1>
        <p>This is my third paragraph!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: OP is trying to learn `flex` and is perfectly valid solution instead of grid. If you are going to suggest grid, then add a `grid` solution to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want to achieve ? :)

```css
.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container-1 div {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 0%;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  flex: 0 0 0%;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 5;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  display: flex;
  /* ADDED */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* ADDED */
  align-items: center;
  /* ADDED */
}

.box-3 p {
  /* ADDED */
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <h1>Box One </h1>
    <p>This is my first paragraph!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <h1>Box Two </h1>
    <p>This is my second paragraph!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <h1>Box Three </h1>
    <p>This is my third paragraph!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to consider a side bar, wherever it may be placed on the screen (top as a header, bottom as a footer, left, right), you first need to consider its positioning as a block element in HTML. For that, please look at how I have re-arranged the HTML elements, **the order matters** because we do not need to use `position: absolute` at all when considering block element positioning.

Now that is done, consider how flex allows you to manage the spacing and alignment of the blocks. I have asked flex to do `space-between` between the box container and the sidebar container. I have also asked flex to manage the positioning of the box elements in the box container div.

This understanding is crucial, being able to look outside the code and visualize the positioning of the block elements will empower you to seek the more correct implementation.

Also as a bonus, I have re-named your class names to be more meaningful to their purpose; and I have also added some color to help you identify the block elements more easily.

*Edit*: I noted you are using the [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property to set the width or rather [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) behavior of each box. I have modified my snippet to reflect this based on your code, this should allow for responsive behavior.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: space-between;
}

.container .box-container {
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .box-container > div {
    background-color: white;
    flex: 0;
}

.container .box-container > div, .sidebar {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container .sidebar {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box-1">
            <h1>Box One</h1>
            <p>This is my first paragraph!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-2">
            <h1>Box Two</h1>
            <p>This is my second paragraph!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h1>Box Three</h1>
        <p>This is my third paragraph!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you assume that the sidebar will always be `100px` and this makes it unresponsive.

Comment: @disinfor I made that assumption freely as there are no specific requirements for the display of the sidebar, the person who asked the question can elaborate if they wish and I can proceed to answer their questions

Comment: Sure, but since they were using percentages in the question and using flex, I would assume that responsiveness is part of the original question. The answer certainly works.

Comment: @disinfor I took your comment and made edits to allow `flex-grow` to determine the size of the sidebar responsively